# Haskell: use Data.Text.replace to replace only the first occurrence of a text value

Tags: haskell

How do I only replace the first occurrence of a "substring" (actually Data.Text.Text) in a Text value in Haskell in the most efficient way?

Comment: Make sure that you don't want to keep calling this iteratively as it's really not the best way to incrementally replace occurrences of text in a string. If you do a lot of it, look into a Rope datastructure or something else clever.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [`breakOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.3/doc/html/Data-Text.html#v:breakOn) the substring,

```
breakOn :: Text -> Text -> (Text, Text)
```

to split the `Text` into two parts at the first occurrence of the pattern, then replace the substring at the start of the second component:

```
replaceOne :: Text -> Text -> Text -> Text
replaceOne pattern substitution text
  | T.null back = text    -- pattern doesn't occur
  | otherwise = T.concat [front, substitution, T.drop (T.length pattern) back] 
    where
      (front, back) = breakOn pattern text
```